# chrome window acts like an iframe (when running with disabled web security)

Tags: google-chrome, security, iframe, cross-domain, chromium

I launch chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag for testing purposes", then my html page is loaded(http://my.page.com/), and opens a new tab using `var wnd1 = window.open('https://other.domain.com')`. When the new page is loaded (in a new tab), I can execute some javascript on the new window object, for instance: `wnd1.document.querySelector(".class1 p")`. So far everything makes sense.
Then again, I open a page from different domain:  `var wnd2 = window.open('https://different.domain2.com')`, and try to access its document with javascript code: `wnd2.document`, but now I get an error that looks related to iframes: "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://my.page.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at :1:4"

This error occurs only with specific domains (in contrast to "regular" domains - msn.com, google.com, etc., which I can open and execute JS code on). Any header that makes it act like an iframe? some other protection methods?